# How show alert for expiration dates in Windows Forms (Visual Basic + Visual Studio)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a database about expiration dates, and I need create an Alert System when the actual dates is close with any date in my database.

In the database, I add a column to know how many days between the actual date and the date of expiration missing.

How can I do this automatically, for example when the form load, automatically updates the days missing in all second column.

I need to create a button where just clicking makes that process.
I attached a screenshot.

Comment: "I attached a screenshot" but you didn't yet.

Comment: put the logic in the form load method

Comment: Please complete your question and please provide some code (in text not screenshot)

Comment: There are quite a number of different concepts going on here, any one of which you will need to get your head around, you need to focus your question a lot more and add sample code you’ve attempted so far and a clear explanation of how it doesn’t met requirements